# Batch edit all events in a week in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have 13+ events that I have in a certain week. I need to move all of them back a week, same times and weekdates, just back a week.
I know that you can drag and drop dates within the weekly view, but:
1) You can't do that with multiple at a time.
2) It's restricted to a week.

This seems like something that should be a basic feature. Any way to get this done without editing each and every event I have?

Comment: If you're going to use drag-and-drop, I'd use the monthly or the custom view.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little bit, but I'm still looking for a batch edit option...

Answer (score 1):

I made [a program in Google Apps Script that can do this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRylapVSejmJJiwzqwFxJvNK7_E__gSM8isaIf-XouU/edit?usp=sharing).

The link is to a Google Spreadsheet that acts as a GUI to a Google Apps Script. The Google Apps Script uses the Calendar API (here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) to perform all the various functions that someone might want to do when editing an event. If you want to see how it works, copy the spreadsheet to your Google Drive and click in the menu "Tools > Script Editor"

Comment: Can you describe what the program does and/or summarize what's at the link?  Otherwise, this answer doesn't stand on its own.

Comment: Just updated my answer

Comment: Please _do not_ use URL shorteners here.

Comment: This Bulk Edit Calendar Events GUI is great!